# Change group pin width with eaglecad?

Tags: cad

I am designing a package in eaglecad and I got the pin width incorrect. I don't want to change all 100 pads manually. Is there a way to select a group and change the dimensions on all the pads?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike, did @Andrew Kohlsmith's answer work for you?  If it did it is customary to accept the answer else respond as to why it did not so the community can continue to search for an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to script this up in eagle's scripting language without too much problem. Something like this:

```
if(library(L)) {
    L.packages(P) {
        P.contacts(C) {
            if(C.smd) {
                C.smd.dx = 10; C.smd.dy = 30; /* or whatever */
            }
        }
    }
}
```